# Texture paint showing a random old render on my model

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

See the following screenshot.
I am trying to paint my model but some random artifacts are showing up on my model and makes it hard to see what I'm painting exactly.

Deleting my models texture, UV map and material does NOT solve it.

I also tried restarting it obviously but without luck.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried appending the model to a new file and seeing if the same thing happens again? I cannot see anything wrong in the screenshot that woudl explain the weirdness.

Comment: .blend would be helpful, with packed textures. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or http://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look to see if you have your old render as a brush texture.[image: brush texture is rendered image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. But this is not the issue. The artifacts appeared before I even painted and nothing is set as a brush texture.

Comment: Please consider appending to a new file or uploading a file for us to look at then.